# org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitOptions.includeGroups() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [NoDbTests]

Tags: java, junit, gradle

I have added this gradle task

and then I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/java/UsersServer/build.gradle' line: 98

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'UsersServer'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitOptions.includeGroups() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [NoDbTests]
```

what is wrong with my syntax?

I saw this tutorial:

```
test {
    useJUnit {
          includeCategories 'linqmap.users.interfaces.NoDbTests'
    //    excludeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryB'
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the snipit from the script thats running. It looks like the script you posted isn't related to what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have used `"excludeCategories"` and not `"includeGroups()"`

```
test {
    useJUnit {
          includeGroups 'linqmap.users.interfaces.NoDbTests'
    //    excludeGroups 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryB'
    }
}
```

should be

```
test {
    useJUnit {
          includeCategories 'linqmap.users.interfaces.NoDbTests'
    }
}
```